# Split a beamer frame

Tags: beamer

How can I split a beamer frame as shown in picture?

I want to put a figure on the top-left minipage 
and a figure in the remaining space.

I don't want lines, I just want to split the frame
and use it as a normal minipage

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give us an MWE. Your picture is not telling very much, to be honest. Do you want a line? What happens to the rest of the frame?

Comment: Sorry, you're right... hope is more clear

Answer (score 6):

**2nd version:**

I understand that what you want is not possible to get it easily. `Beamer` frames can be divided by columns as many times you need, but not recombine them once they are create. You can define two columns on upper part and only one below them, but it's not possible to join right upper column with lower part.

The best I can do is:

1. Fill an upper left column with the text you want. It's like a `minipage` because it's possible to define its width.
2. Add a previously defined figure with transparent background which can be placed on bottom right corner with `TikZ` or `eso-pic`.

Following code shows an example. It uses `TikZ` to place figure.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Nice frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[anchor=south east] at ([shift={(-1,1)}]current page.south east) {\includegraphics{sensetitol-2}};}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**1st answer:**

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Nice frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};

\node[fill=white, anchor=north west] at (A.north west)  {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to divide the frame in two pages as in my picture and then I want to put in these pages whatever I want: blocks, items, pictures, tikz pictures

Comment: You could create a Tikz macro with 2 input arguments, one for the small box and one for the big one and you just type what you want in each one

Comment: @clfmaris I've updated my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Yeah! It what I was looking for! Thank you @Ignasi

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just to position both figures in a certain way I would suggest two options:

1) Use a graphics editor like Inkscape to create a single figure out of the two original figures.

2) Use overpic package so you can insert the small figure on top of the big one ([overpic small example](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/overpic/opic-abs.pdf)). The advantage of this option is that you can easily reposition the images when editing the tex file.

It can probably be done using Tikz but I am not that skilled in it so I can't suggest how to do it.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I would like to re-use this frame even for other environment as blocks, itemize...

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the figures as a background?

Comment: I edited the question