# Split Frame into itemize and figure

Tags: itemize, minipage

I am working on an presentation and would like to put a small graphic in the top right corner of the frame. The rest of the frame should be itemized.  So it should look like the posted image does.

I found something about minipages, but it seems to split the frame just into columns?

Thanks!

[image]

Edit: Here is my try with minipage.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item I want to itemize stuff! 
                \item I want to itemize stuff! Sometimes the \\ text might be 
                    longer. So I hope its go-\\ing to be formated correctly. Would be \\ kinda cool. 
                \item I want to itemize stuff! And this long text should be placed under the picture.
                \item I want to itemize stuff!
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item this is a test! I hope at the end of the day my problem will be solved somehow. 
                \end{itemize}

            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/Ei.jpg}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX ! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Hi Bernard! Thanks for your support. I edited my post and added an example.

Comment: Taka a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298270/split-a-beamer-frame

Comment: Hi @clfmaris! Thank your for linking the other thread. I didn't find it when I googled by myself.
Seems, my problem can't be solved in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to split in three mini pages and write the itemizes separately.

divide the frame in two pages, "top-page" and "bottom-page":
  the top-page is then divided in two pages left-page and right-page

this is not a nice way, but i think it can work